# Localization message when submitting an App in iTunes connect for review

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

What does the following message supposed to mean? I added those new localizations to the app and I'm now submitting the app for review.

[image]

Does that mean App 4.1 version (I'm releasing now) will not have those localizations available in the app store until I release another version? (V 4.2 for example) I'm a little bit confused because some of the previous localizations didn't appear immediately in the store after releasing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must upload a new version if you want the new information in the App Store.

Always remember to save your changes before submit.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm submitting the app for review..Please read my question again...I have did some changes.

Comment: Hmmm, the image was confusing, because it shows that you are submitting 4.1. So that version 4.1 is already in the store (released)? If so, you must enter the new name and upload a new version (4.2).

On the other hand, if you haven't released version 4.1 yet, you can do the submission again with a new build (4.1.2 or whatever you want to call it).

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour as the "App Name" field is **not** tied to a specific version in iTunes Connect in contrast to description, keywords etc.

Its displayed a little bit "awkward" in iTunes Connect by the yellow circle and the highlighted app name.

[image]

The popup basically "confirms" that the changes you made to the app name don't go live immediately for your current version (I assume 4.0 in your example), but only for the approved version 4.1

Comment: Hi! Thanks but the v4.1  I'm submitting it for review in my case.

Comment: It's a little bit misunderstanding, but it's still exactly as I wrote. The popup just tells you that the changes won't be available for v4.0, but only for v4.1 once it's approved.